# In Swift, is it possible to extract #function from a passed closure?

Tags: swift, function, closures

Consider this function:

```
func doSomething ( closure: ( String, Any? ) -> Void )
{
    let serialisedFunction = #function
    print( serialisedFunction )
}
```

It will literally print `doSomething(closure:)`

Great! But how does one get the parallel `#function` property out of the passed closure?

Something akin to:

```
func doSomething ( closure: ( String, Any? ) -> Void )
{
    let serialisedClosure = closure.#function
    print( serialisedClosure )
}
```

*Context*: I have a signals/event bus, that is passed closures to call when signals/events occur. I want to create unique keys for these signals/events, to ensure that they are listened to once *and once only*, therefore I am trying to create keys based upon serialised objects, including the listening closures.

Thank you.

Comment: Since closures can be anonymous, this will be difficult. What would you expect to be printed if we called `doSomething` as, say, `doSomething() { _, _ in () }`?

Comment: I'd suggest you wrap your closures in, say, a struct containing only a `(String, Any?) -> Void` closure and an id, say `let id : Int`. You could easily conform such a struct to `Hashable` allowing you to have a `[YourClosureStruct: Bool]` dictionary that you could use to make certain the signal/events are only listened to once.

Comment: Nice idea @dfri, thanks, I'll give that a go.